# Remove Comment Tag From POST Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using JQuery and trying to make a post request, and the response I get is of type

```
/*this is the string i need*/
```

Now I'm trying to access the string I need, but for some scoping issue, I don't seem to be getting it right.

My Code is:

```
$.get( "/geturl", function( data ) {
        console.log(hereStr(data)); ==> prints /*this is the string i need*/
});


function hereStr(f) {
  return f.
      replace(/^[^\/]+\/\*!?/, '').
      replace(/\*\/[^\/]+$/, '');
}
```

but my console.log just prints the same string with the comment tags as shown above
Is my Regex wrong? Or is this some scoping issue?

Any pointers would be much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: It is not a scoping issue. Your `hereStr()` function is incorrect.

Comment: What should it be then?

Comment: `f.replace(/\/\*(.+)\*\//, '$1');` will give you everything between the comment start and comment end.

Answer (score 2):

A corrected version of your `hereStr()` function:

```
function hereStr(f) {
  return f.replace(/\/\*(.+)\*\//, '$1');
}
```